# Calculate start middle and end of a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math

I need a start, middle and end value of any given number, it doesn't have to be equally distributed, just needs a bit of logic. Example:

`var parts = 3;`

Obviously, I could devide this by 3 and get an even devised result `start: 1; middle: 1; end: 1`.

However if the user was to put in something like:

`var parts = 8;`

In my eyes, the answer would be `start: 2; middle: 4; end: 2`.

I need to perform a basic task depending on the length of the 'parts' variable.

Example:

I need to calculate the start, middle and end values so I can do something like this.

```
for (var t=0; t < start; t++){
    console.log('Start');
}
for (var t=0; t < middle; t++){
    console.log('Middle');
}
for (var t=0; t < end; t++){
    console.log('End');
}
```

How could I calculate this?

Comment: can you please add any constraints?.i mean can you be more specific?

Comment: How must the numbers be distributed?

Comment: I added another example, I hope this helps, the numbers need to be distributed evenly, and if they can't, the middle would take the higher value, like my example with the parts variable == 8. @TimeToogo

Comment: see the solution below..hope this is what u r looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, as soon as I left home, and got into my car, I remembered about the [Modulo Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). While most of your answers do work and I there was one answer that was using Modulos, I have to be selfish here and most a much more simpler and correct version.

```
var parts=9;
var start = end = middle = (parts - (parts % 3)) / 3;
middle += parts % 3;
```

But thank you all for your help!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B5tap/

Comment: This makes very bad use of the modulo operator; `Math.floor(parts / 3)` is easier to understand than `(parts - (parts % 3)) / 3`.

Comment: I find that reading something as how it's supposed to be written rather than a javascripts interpretation of the Modulo function is better to read. @Jack

Comment: I'm not seeing which part is an interpretation of the modulo function? The part of your code I mentioned deals with the division only.

Comment: I did include a link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Modulo_operation_expression, this is how Modulo is written with javascript having to re write it using the math module.

Comment: If the aim was to not use `Math`, then that would be fine I suppose; again, I was merely pointing out that to calculate the common part it would be easier without the modulo.

Comment: I also don't understand how "Divide by 3 and find the remainder, then subtract the remainder from the original number and divide by 3" is supposed to be simpler than "Divide by 3 and ignore the fractional remainder"

Comment: It's a very simple expression, it's only 3 lines long to define 3 different variables. Yes I agree that readability is better over less code, however in this case I find it very easy to read still

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts, segment, start, middle, end;

parts = 8; // Obviously this value would be defined elsewhere

segment = Math.floor(parts / 3);

start = end = segment;
middle = parts - (segment * 2);
```

Comment: Yes, almost. You meant `middle = parts - 2 * segment` unless I'm much mistaken :)

Comment: This is cool didn't know about this, however I decided to go with my own answer, it's just simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Solution:

```
var start,end,middle;
var parts=10;
if(parts%3==0)
{
start=end=middle=parts/3;
}
else
{
start=parseInt(parts/3);
end=parseInt(parts/3);
middle=parts-start-end;
}
console.warn(start+" "+end+" "+middle);
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9WUZ/4/

Comment: Thankyou for posting this, your example seems to not work though? Although I have posted my own answer here, it seems to be much simpler :)

Comment: @ShannonHochkins Oh.I forget to update the fiddle.Now it got updated.I saw the solution pretty good. :)